# Intellij IDEA 14 error: {} is not assignable to type hash (JS)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc, intellij-14

Consider following Javascript code example

```
/**
 * @param {hash}   options
 * @param {string} options.param1
 * @param {string} options.param2
 */
function doSomething(options) {
    options = options || {}; // Error: "{} is not assignable to type hash"
    // ...
}
```

Why does IDEA say {} can't be assigned to hash?

## UPDATE

JSDoc style was picked up from Zimbra frontend source code.
For example, look at [DwtComposite](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/zimlet/zcs/8.6.0/jsapi-zimbra-doc/symbols/src/WebRoot_js_ajax_dwt_widgets_DwtComposite.js.html) constructor.

The error message itself

[image]

Comment: I guess the hash comes from window.location.hash? The issue comes from casting problem.

Comment: I've just pasted your code into my current javascript project, and found no such error. In what way does IntelliJ tell you that this is an error?

Comment: type hash? Shouldn't it be type `{object}` or `{PropertiesHash}`

Comment: I've updated my question with information you asked.